# populate or aggregator, how?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to get only all messages related to the projects posted by user.
I don't think there is a way to do so using populate because we have to get the user id from the other collection and then render messages using his id which is "submittedBy" in the project schema.

I am trying aggregator but it is also not working.

Any help or clue would be appreciated.

**message Schema:**

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
content:{
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
projectId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Form'
},
imageId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Image'
},
sender:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}, 
readBy:[{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
}, {timestamps:true});
```

**Project schema:**

```
const FormSchema = new Schema({
submittedBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
logoName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
industry: [{
    type: String,
    trim: true
}],
logoType: [{
    type: String,
    trim: true
}],
colors: [{
    type: String,
    trim: true
}],
tagline: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
org: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
communicate: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
deadline : {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
services: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
package: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
assignedTo: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
   }
}, {timestamps:true})
```

---

I tried population but I don't think it will work or efficient.

So I am using aggregation but it's not working:

---

```
var objId =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user._id);

        results = await Model.aggregate([
            
            {
              $lookup:
                {
                  from: "forms",
                  localField: "projectId",
                  foreignField: "_id",
                  as: "tags"
                }
           },
           { $unwind: "$tags" },
           {$match:{ 'tags.submittedBy': userId }},
           

         ]).exec(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results)
        });
```

Result After Combining two collections:

```
{
_id: 609bd3772583c56dd3e302d3,
readBy: [],
content: 'Remove Tagline and align.',
sender: 604db5708cf232652cd4469e,
imageId: 6099964c2583c56dd3e302c3,
projectId: 60968eed2583c56dd3e302ac,
createdAt: 2021-05-12T13:09:11.060Z,
updatedAt: 2021-05-12T13:09:11.060Z,
__v: 0,
tags: {
  _id: 60968eed2583c56dd3e302ac,
  industry: [Array],
  logoType: [Array],
  colors: [Array],
  logoName: 'global consultancy services',
  tagline: 'Follow your dreams',
  org: 'We guide students who seeks to study overseas e.g. the UK. We offer consultancy services to students from selecting a university to getting visa and then getting in the country.',
  communicate: '3 concepts\r\n' +
    'Keep "Indra global " big AND bold\r\n' +
    'and "consultancy services" below it.\r\n' +
    'In one concept you can use IGCS initials to create icon form'
  deadline: '2021-05-12',
  services: '',
  package: 'undefined',
  submittedBy: 60968eed2583c56dd3e302ab,
  createdAt: 2021-05-08T13:15:25.661Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-05-10T08:28:18.587Z,
  __v: 0,
  assignedTo: '6050d8485cc8bb6a20ef36fa'
}
```

}
]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Is the type of `res.session.user_id` the same as the type of the `sender` field?

Comment: I am getting no errors but empty [ ], yes req.session.user_id is the same as the type of the sender.

Comment: You might want to check that  - `req.session` fields are usually Strings, not ObjectIds

Comment: {$match:{ 'tags.submittedBy': '604db5708cf232652cd4469e' }}  I am directly using object Id like this but still its not working. @Joe

Comment: That is a string, cast it to ObjectId if 'tags.submittedBy' is an ObjectId.

Comment: I don't think tags.submittedBy is an object, please check the results above after combining two collections. @joe

Comment: Note the lack of quotation marks around those values, as opposed to the `assignedTo` field. AssignedTo is a string, the others are the prettifier displaying an ObjectId

Comment: Thank you so much @joe I was behind it for the last 2 days, finally, it got solved with your help.

Comment: just one last question, can we achieve the same results using populate?